# How can i take value and deduct it from other in html using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
I want jquery for taking value from `<td>` and will deduct it from h2 tag in final output place.This is the for loop exact area.
           <% photolist.forEach(function(photo){ %>  
    <tr>                        
         <td id="likescount"><%=photo.likes_count%></td>
      </tr>
     <%})%>
```

I want to access this count from array to substract.

Answer (score 3):

No need for jQuery

```
const h2 = document.querySelector(".totallikes");
h2.textContent -= document.getElementById("likescount").textContent;
```

**NOTE**: The minus casts to number

```js
const h2 = document.querySelector(".totallikes");
h2.textContent -= document.getElementById("likescount").textContent;
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-3">
  <div class="widget style1 lazur-bg">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-5x"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="col-8 text-right">
        <span>Total no. of likes </span>
        <h2 class="totallikes font-bold">45</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="likescount">5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If it MUST be jQuery then

```
const $h2 = $(".totallikes");
$h2.text($h2.text() - $("#likescount").text())
```

```js
const $h2 = $(".totallikes");
$h2.text($h2.text() - $("#likescount").text())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-3">
  <div class="widget style1 lazur-bg">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-5x"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="col-8 text-right">
        <span>Total no. of likes </span>
        <h2 class="totallikes font-bold">45</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="likescount">5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```